# Excel 2010 open more than one spread sheet in same window

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I open more than one spreadsheet in the same window so that if I close one the others stay open or if I close the last one Excel stays open?  Thank you.

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is.  Open multiple files and close each file when desired using the individual file close (the lower "X").  How are you trying to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of Excel you are using. In general you can do this by changing the mode of the spreadsheet (not of Excel) to 'restore window' instead of 'maximize' - using Excel 2007 I've shown the button highlighted in yellow below:

[image: Excel 2007 showing highlighted restore window button]

Now you will find that you can see and use each spreadsheet independently within the larger Excel window. In fact you can do this anyway even if they are maximised by using CTRL + F6 (or 'Switch Windows' on the ribbon).